# How to determine the fourth coefficient in the power series expansion of $(1 + \ln(1-x))^{-1}$?

Tags: power-series

> $\dfrac{1}{1+\ln(1-x)}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n x^n$, then $a_4=$?

**My approach:**

> \begin{align*}\dfrac{1}{1+\ln(1-x)}&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n(\ln(1-x))^n\\
> &=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\left(\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{x^m}{m}\right)^n\end{align*}
>
> Then $$a_4=(-1)^1\cdot\dfrac{1}{4}+(-1)^2\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{2}+\binom{2}{1}\cdot 1\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}\right)+ (-1)^3 \cdot\binom{3}{1}\cdot 1\cdot1\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}+ (-1)^4\cdot 1\cdot1\cdot 1\cdot 1=\dfrac{1}{6}$$

But the answer is $\dfrac{11}{3}$, ignoring $(-1)^n$. What’s the problem?

Comment: You could just calculate $f^{iv}(x),$ the $4$th derivative of $f(x)=(1+\log (1-x))^{-1}.$ Then $a_4=f^{iv}(0)/4!$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Oh, yes! Thanks!

Comment: Tedious but guaranteed to work.But  I like your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out a negative sign in the logarithmic series:
$$\begin{align*}
  \dfrac{1}{1+\ln(1-x)}
  &=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n(\ln(1-x))^n\\
  &=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n
    \left(-\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{x^m}{m}\right)^n\\
  &=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}
    \left(\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{x^m}{m}\right)^n\end{align*}$$
and expanding this carefully gives the coefficient of $x^4$ as $\frac{11}3$.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve got it!+1

Answer (score 2):

*Not smart at all.*

In this problem, you are not asked for $a_n$ or even for $a_{123}$ but just for $a_4$.

Being lazy, what I would have done is to use
$$\log(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^5}{5}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{1+\ln(1-x)}=\frac 1 {1-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^5}{5}+O\left(x^6\right)}$$ and then long division to get 
$$\frac{1}{1+\ln(1-x)}=1+x+\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{7 x^3}{3}+\frac{11 x^4}{3}+\frac{347
   x^5}{60}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I’ll practise more.

Comment: @Benny. You are welcome ! As you noticed, I am lazy.